# How to convert string VCard into a vcf file

Tags: python, html, flask

How can I convert this into a vcf file?

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Nicolas Rizzo
MAIL;TYPE=home:nizzoeh@hotmail.com
END:VCARD
```

I generated the above VCard by doing this:

```
j = vobject.vCard()
        o = j.add('fn')
        o.value = rowr.name

        o = j.add('mail')
        o.type_param = "email"
        o.value = rowr.email

        vcard = j.serialize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply write it into a text file.

Here is a fully working example :

```
import vobject

from types import SimpleNamespace # for testing
list_person = [SimpleNamespace(name="test1", email="test1@contoso.com"),SimpleNamespace(name="test2", email="test2@contoso.com")]

vcf_file_path = 'rep_tel.vcf'

with open(vcf_file_path , 'w',encoding='utf8') as file_vcard:
    for rowr in list_person:
        vcard = vobject.vCard()
        o = vcard.add('fn')
        o.value = rowr.name

        o = vcard.add('email')
        o.type_param = 'INTERNET'
        o.value = rowr.email

        file_vcard.write(vcard.serialize())
```